# Find a functiom, that is equal 1 on the interval

Tags: functions

Have to find a function that would describe the following situation - suppose given circle and  function depending on the angle $f (\varphi)$. The function should be 1 if $\varphi \in (a, b)$ and zero otherwise, where $a$ and $b$ - a point on a circle. Now i have only 1 idea 
Heaviside ($\varphi$) - Heaviside ($\varphi-\epsilon$), but this function is 1 only on arc $(0, \epsilon)$

Comment: Why not multiply two Heaviside functions?

Comment: @flonk both methods work just fine. But you have to shift the origin of the function. Stretching and moving the function fixes the problem.

Comment: @orion Sure, I just thought multiplying to be more intuitive to beginners (in a logical sense), than shifting.

Comment: @orion Should I use Heaviside(φ-a)-Heaviside(φ-b)?

Comment: @user140895 yes, that solves the problem.